# Getting Python Django 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I wrote the PUT request API to set the user password. I wrote so many views but I am not experiencing any issue like in below view function.

views.py

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([])
def setForgotPasswordWithNewPassword(request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    user = User.objects.get(username=data['username'])
    secret_key = request.data['secretkey']
    backend_secretkey = cache.get('reset_pwd_%s' % (data['username']))
    if backend_secretkey:
        if backend_secretkey == secret_key:
            if user:
                user.set_password(data['password'])
                # print(user.password)
                user.save()
                return Response({"msg":"Your password has been successfully changed"},status=200)
            else:
                return Response({"error":"Username does not exist on our system"},status=403)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Your not authorized to use this link"}, status=403)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Your password link has been expired, please try again"}, status=403)
```

Using Postman I am not getting any Exception on command line. but when I am hitting this API using my Angular project getting the below exception and due this exception wsgi server loaded again so angular loaded to again front page. But changing password working. so I am curious to know about this error which I am experiencing.

error:

```
[15/Jun/2020 00:34:01] "PUT /api/setForgotPasswordWithNewPwd/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[15/Jun/2020 00:34:01] "PUT /api/setForgotPasswordWithNewPwd/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49954)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 119, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 197, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 114, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Using Postman tool calling not getting any Exception like above

My Angular calling:

```
setForgotPassword(data):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.put<any>(this._base_url+this._setForgotPassword_url,data)
  }
```

Typescript:

```
setPassword(secretkey){
    this.data.secretkey = secretkey
    console.log(this.data)
    this.usr_srv.setForgotPassword(this.data).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        // let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog,{
        //   data: {msg: 'Your password has been successfully set',color:"green"}
        // });
        // dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        //   this._router.navigate(['/login'])
        // });
      },
      err =>{
        console.log(err)
        // let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog,{
        //   data: {msg: err.error.error,color:"red"}
        // });
        // dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        //   this._router.navigate(['/login'])
        // });
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: It is telling you that `self.environ` and `self.status` don't point to any objects at the time they are used, but are both references to `None`.    You need to either check for `None` or find the error upstream of that logic.

Comment: somehow it got resolved due to some code changes in Angular front end side, I don't know why how front end was affecting the back end server